# Evaluate convergence of force constants in crystal with increasing cutoff

Tags: computational-physics, phonons

I have a crystal with 2 atomic species, A and B. I'm interested in the interatomic force constants (IFCs) and I have a program that computes them for a given supercell. Basically, I have to provide the unit cell and a supercell derived from it and the program returns the force constants between each atom of the unit cell and its neighbours in the supercell according to a given cutoff. This information is then used to extract the frequencies in reciprocal space.
I have to evaluate the convergence of the IFCs by increasing the cutoff.

Let's take the displacement of atom $i$ along direction $\mu$, $u_{i\mu}$, and that of atom $j$ along direction $\nu$, $u_{j\nu}$. Then the program gives me $\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial u_{i\mu}\partial u_{j\nu}}$ (evaluated at zero displacement); let's call it $k$, for simplicity.
Let's also say that I launch this calculation with two values for the cutoff for atom $i$: $r_c=x$ and $r_c=y$ with $y>x$. Let's call the respective force constant $k_1$ and $k_2$. I have to evaluate if these force constants are similar or not. My first thought is to compute the relative error:
$$\varepsilon=\frac{k_2-k_1}{|k_1|}$$
This is ok as long as both constants are different from zero. But there are cases where they are not. As a first thing, we can say that when both are zero, then the error can be set to $0$ by definition.

However, sometimes only one of the two constants is zero. The trivial example is everytime for atom $i$ the atom $j$ is considered as neighbour according to the larger cutoff and not for the narrower one. In these cases all the constants associated to the pair of atoms $(i,j)$ will be $0$ for the smaller cutoff and non-zero for the larger one. This means that I cannot compute the relative error. So I'm looking for a measure of the error in these cases.

One way I thought is to normalise the difference with respect to the average value, but for the cases I just depicted the error would always be equal to 2:
$$2\frac{k_2 - k_1}{|k_2 + k_1|}=2\frac{k_2 - 0}{|k_2 + 0|} = \pm2$$
This measures is not useful because it's constant independent on the value of $k_2$.

Another way would be normalising with respect to the "absolute-maximum" of the two. Again in these problematic cases I would get a useless constant measure equal to 1:
$$\frac{k_2-k_1}{max(|k_2|, |k_1|)}=\frac{k_2-0}{|k_2|}=\pm1$$

Then I had another idea, but I don't know if it makes sense or not: I would compute the relative error when both $k_1$ and $k_2$ are non-zero, and for the problematic cases I would compare the non-zero constant ($k_2$) to the average difference
$\left<k_2-k_1\right>$ computed over all non-problematic cases.
I tried this way and I got really strange results, hence I guess this way of computing the error makes not much sense.

Do you have any advice about how to do this?
Thanks